# asp.net core api Redirect Unauthorizes request to another url

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an API project built in asp.net core
One of the Functions can be accessed only when Authorized using Bearer token.

The API is called from a mobile application by scanning a QR(so it can be called outside my app), so when a request is not authorized i want to redirect the user to the app in android/app store.

I'm looking for something to update in program.cs so that every unauthorized call will redirect to android/app store.

my programs.cs :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
  builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
  ));

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["appsettings:Audience"],
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["appsettings:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["appsettings:Secret"]))
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddDependencies();
builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
        c.SupportedSubmitMethods( new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SubmitMethod[] { Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SubmitMethod.Options });
    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: This is something that should be handled client-side. You mobile application should open the app store when it receives 401 Unauthorized response from the API.

Comment: The api is called from a QR code, user can scan outside the application, so the solution should be handled in the server side (if it's possible)